# Is it okay to have different version of ROS in the remote pc and the turtleblot pc?

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example I have ros-melodic on remote pc and
ros-kinetic on turtlebot pc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311032/is-it-okay-to-have-different-version-of-ros-in-the-remote-pc-and-the-turtleblot-pc?/) by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2018-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-19**:
We're all here to help, but this specific question has come up at least 10 times in the past 2 years. A quick Google (`different ROS versions site:answers.ros.org`) returns at least 1700 results for me.

Please try to use the search, ROS Answers is not a slow chat forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There may be some issues between versions but I've had success using three different versions of ROS at once (Hydro, Indigo, and Kinetic) and I had to do some work arounds (mainly for Hydro, which is pretty old) but everything worked pretty well. Other, than a "you *should* be ok, but there *may* be issues" I don't think there's too much that can be said except for try it out and see what happens.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on 2018-12-18**:
Thank you for your comment :D